# Allow ipv6 address in Azure firewall

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, firewall, ipv6

I need access to a SQL-database running in Azure, but i have been assigned an ipv6-address. This does not seem to be supported in the Azure firewall settings. Is there any way to get access without getting a new ip? Asterisk is not accepted in the ip-field.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're looking at that page over IPv4 and your IP address is http://checkip.amazonaws.com.

Azure SQL does not listen on IPv6 (yet).

Comment: Thanks! Both whatismyipaddress.com and whatismyip.com only showed the ipv6 address. Will i always have an ipv4 address in addition to the ipv6?

Comment: For the next 10 years most probably yes. Even if you only see an IPv6 address in `ipconfig /all`, your network admins have a bag of tricks to make the IPv4 internet still accessible. Both sites default to IPv6, that's why you see IPv6. http://ip4.me for example resolves to IPv4.

Comment: Unless your provider is crap like mine is and offers 'Dual Stack Lite'/CGNat. In which case you'll be able to access the ipv4 world, but might not have a stable address for firewall rules like these.

Comment: You can always `allow any any`. It's not the BEST of practices but you still have the security provided by the secret in your connection string.

Comment: Alternatively you could programatically discover you current IPv4 and add it to the firewall exceptions with a REST call. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-configure-firewall-settings-rest